# AttributeError when trying to run simple ETL code

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

I've read through a ton of other threads and can't find a solution to this, so appreciate anyone's input on how to approach this please!

Completing a Python for Data Engineering course, with this project on web scraping. I'm getting the 'AttributeError' below when trying to create a function that extracts data from XML, CSV and JSON files.

> AttributeError - Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
> 1 log("Extract phase Started")
> ----> 2 extracted_data = extract()
> 3 log("Extract phase Ended")
> 4 extracted_data
>
> in extract()
> 29     # Lastly, process all xml files
> 30     for xmlFile in glob.glob("*.xml"):
> ---> 31         extracted_data = extracted_data.append(xmlExtract(xmlFile), ignore_index=True)
> 32
> 33     return extracted_data
>
> in xmlExtract(xmlFile)
> 15     root = tree.getroot()
> 16     for person in root:
> ---> 17         name = person.find("name").text
> 18         height = float(person.find("height").text)
> 19         weight = float(person.find("weight").text)
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

This is the code snippet the error is referring to:

```py
def xmlExtract(xmlFile):
    dframe = pddf(columns=["name", "height", "weight"])
    tree = ET.parse(xmlFile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for person in root:
        name = person.find("name").text
        height = float(person.find("height").text)
        weight = float(person.find("weight").text)
        dframe = dframe.append({"name":name, "height":height, "weight":weight}, ignore_index=True)
    return dframe
```

Appreciate any pointers on where to start please.

P.S. 'pddf' is pandas.dataframe imported distinctively from pandas - `from pandas import DataFrame as pddf` - because I was getting an error with `import pandas as pd`, then using pd.dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Some calls to `.find` are returning `None`. You have to check if the value is `None` first before calling `.text`.

```
def xmlExtract(xmlFile):
    dframe = pddf(columns=["name", "height", "weight"])
    tree = ET.parse(xmlFile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for person in root:
        name = person.find("name").text if person.find("name") else None
        height = float(person.find("height").text) if person.find("height") else None
        weight = float(person.find("weight").text) if person.find("weight") else None

        dframe = dframe.append({"name": name, "height": height, "weight": weight}, ignore_index=True)
    return dframe
```

<sub>This code isn't the best. It's just an example.</sub>

Comment: Thank you Maicon! That has allowed the dataframe to return, but the strange thing is that there are a lot of rows/columns outside of what I'm retrieving from the XML, JSON and CSV files. At least that gives me something to explore further now. Thanks again!